# Rxjava + Retrofit Throwing OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android

When I use Retrofit with rxjava, some machine throwing OOM, this is log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again
at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:920)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1338)
at okhttp3.ConnectionPool.put(ConnectionPool.java:135)
at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$1.put(OkHttpClient.java:149)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:188)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:129)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:98)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:109)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:124)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:145)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:170)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:60)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:171)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1$1.request(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:80)
at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.setProducer(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:76)
at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:152)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:138)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:9861)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:221)
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152) 
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

my retrofit code:

```
  HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    if (BuildConfig.LOG_DEBUG)
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    else
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .connectTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ConstantValue.URL + "/")
            .client(client)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

and my request code:

```
public interface GetUserFriendUsersService {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("IM/GetUserFriendUsers")
Observable<ResponseBody> getUserFriendUsers(@Field("UserID")String UserID);}

 public void getUserFriendUsers(String userID, Subscriber<List<Users>> subscriber) {
    retrofit.create(GetUserFriendUsersService.class)
            .getUserFriendUsers(userID)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(new HttpResultFunc())
            .map(new Func1<JSONObject, List<Users>>() {
                @Override
                public List<Users> call(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                    List<Users> users = JSON.parseArray(jsonObject.getString("users"), Users.class);
                    if (users.size() == 0)
                        throw new CustomizeException("no data");
                    return users;
                }
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(subscriber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The .observeOn() should be in front of map(),and in back of unsubscribeOn()

Answer (score 0):

Posted the same question at [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/issues/387#issuecomment-321008133) github.

The problem is that Schedulers.io() uses a cached thread pool without a limit and thus is trying to create 1500 threads. You should consider using a Scheduler that has a fixed limit of threads, or using RxJava 2.x's parallel() operator to parallelize the operation to a fixed number of workers.

If you're using raw Retrofit by default it uses OkHttp's dispatcher which limits the threads to something like 64 (with a max of 5 per host). That's why you aren't seeing it fail.

If you use createAsync() when creating the RxJava2CallAdapterFactory it will create fully-async Observable instances that don't require a subscribeOn and which use OkHttp's Dispatcher just like Retrofit would otherwise. Then you only need observeOn to move back to the main thread, and you avoid all additional thread creation.